# Op-amp subtractor - why is the output wrong?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm currently designing a power supply and I want the power supply to have current limiting, so I designed a simple subtractor circuit to sense the output current:

[image]

To test the circuit on a breadboard, I used an LM358P op-amp, because it's a single supply op-amp and the datasheet says that its output can go all the way to zero, and I used 1% 100k resistors.

I set my power supply to 10V, connected a load and measured the voltage drop across the 0.1 ohm shunt and the output of the subtractor, and the result baffled me:

[image]

The DMM on the left reads the drop across the shunt resistor and the DMM on the right reads the output of the subtractor. It's almost 10 times higher than the expected output!

I added a 100ohm resistor to load the op-amp (I thought that the op-amp's output needs to be loaded to get a proper result), but the voltage just dropped to something like 200mV.

Here's a picture of my test setup:
[image]

Just to make sure the op-amp is properly working, I swapped the load and the current sense resistor (low-side current sensing) and configured my op-amp as a voltage follower.

[image]

I turned on the power supply and measured the voltage drop across the shunt and the output of the op-amp, and sure enough, it works:

[image]

If the op-amp is fine (or is it?), then why does the subtractor circuit not work correctly?

Here's a picture of the op-amp. This is a genuine part, right?
[image]

---

As andy suggested, 1% resistors just aren't good enough:

[image]

And 0.1% resistors don't give a particularly good result as well

[image]

With a 10ohm shunt (Simon's suggestion) and 1% resistors, there is still a large error.

[image]

But Using 0.1% resistors here gives good results

[image]

But I obviously cant use a 10ohm shunt, so I guess I have to look for other current sensing options (like a hall effect sensor).

---

One last simulation for simon

[image]

Also,

[image]

reference designators as per [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html).

If you plug in the values,

[image]

Comment: it should work, but maybe your 100k resistors are slightly mismatched so the gain is slightly more than -1 ? In that case the output would need to go negative. The amp will saturate and give wrong results.

Comment: Check the input common mote voltage range in the (should have been linked) datasheet. Also clarify how the opamp is powered.

Comment: @user_1818839 The input common mode voltage in this circuit is pretty much mid-supply.

Comment: The LM358 is good down to the negative rail for inputs and output.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your schematic, or the idea, it should work. My money is on a wiring error. That photo of your circuit is next to useless, I can't see what's going where. I suggest your rebuild the circuit, in a manner that makes it easy to follow on the schematic, and doesn't hide *anything* in a photo. Label those wires too, they could be connected to the moon for all I know.

Comment: I'm claiming your money @SimonFitch because the differential amplifier with poor tolerance resistors trying to measure current on a CM rail of 10 volts is not going to work (irrespective of wiring errors). How much money is in your pocket?

Comment: @SimonFitch I can guarantee that there is no wiring error. Yes, the photo is next to useless, but I included it because I'm sure someone will ask for it if it isn't there. The circuit is simple and there are no wiring errors.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth, ok, then you have AndyAka's suggestion which is that with such a small potential difference across 0.1Ω you can't trust the output. So my next suggestion is to use a larger sense resistor, to get a *much* larger (> 1V) voltage across it, and see what happens.

Comment: @SimonFitch will try it and get back to you (you'll have to wait until next week, unfortunately)

Comment: Switch amps to one that includes the +ve supply as a valid input voltage, and then sense the current across the resistor without the huge common mode voltage offset. There are several ways to get the resulting output voltage ground-referred if you need that. One is a further diff-amp, but if the first has 100x gain, then the second amp is 100 times less sensitive to common mode with the same tolerance resistors. Another way that some commercial solutions use is to drive a current source from the +ve rail down to a grounded resistor, read the voltage on the resistor.

Comment: @SimonFitch I've edited the post with simulation results. Take a look.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth as everyone has pointed out, opamp input offset currents and voltage, and component tolerances swamp the output, that's established, I think. However I don't see how this can account for the 800% error your voltmeter is measuring.

Comment: @SimonFitch The output of my setup was close to 10 times higher than it should be and the LTspice simulation shows the same thing. Again, there was nothing wrong with my wiring.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth They all show offsets reasonable for the conditions you simulated, but none of them show the 500mV error your meters showed. Show me a simulation with the original current of 6.4mA, and worst case resistors, please.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth sorry, I meant 640mA.

Comment: @SimonFitch check the update. Also, the load current was 640mA when Vin was 30V. I need to change that in my question. I did several tests from Vin = 0.5V to Vin = 32.5V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130201/discussion-between-prathik-prashanth-and-simon-fitch).

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth Well, it seems you have found your source of 500mV offset. I have nothing to add except that AndyAka was right, and I overlooked the possibility of a 30V power supply being the cause. Sorry to have pressed so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I set my power supply to 10V*

It's completely down to the accuracy of the 100 kohm resistors. If one pair is producing a Thevenin voltage (5 volts) that is 1 % high and the other pair is 1 % low then that is +50 mV offset on one pair and a -50 mV offset on the other pair. Given that you are trying to measure a voltage of about 30 mV (if we look at your final circuit readings) you are not going to get this to work with 1% resistors. This is an age old problem with this type of circuit.

Small additional errors come from input bias offset currents running in the resistors. It can be as high as 30 nA and, 30 nA through 100 k&ohm, is an error of 3 mV. Input offset voltages are also present up to a level of about 3 mV.

Comment: So will using something like 0.1% resistors fix the problem, or should I look for other options (like a hall effect sensor)?

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth there are dedicated chips that will do this based around an op-amp whose input range includes the positive supply rail. They output a current that is a small ratio value of the measured current and, a ground connected resistor converts that current into a ground referenced positive voltage. Available from TI and ADI. Off the top of my head I can't think of part numbers but, you can build it from an op-amp and a MOSFET. OK, LT6105 springs to mind. And, I think the MAX4172 also works.

Comment: Just for fun Andy :  no one mentioned the other half op-amp floating inputs.

Comment: @Marla those old dual op-amps can probably stand that situation!!